# Are there free backup clients that will allow me to backup to an offsite server?

Tags: windows, backup

I am looking for free backup clients that will allow me to backup directories, documents, etc to an offsite Windows server. The clients will be a mix of Windows, Linux and Mac however predominantly Windows.I am looking for a client or clients that utilize encrypted backups as opposed to just FTP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a mix of programs.  One of the more well known programs is CrashPlan. It offers encryption and backup to a cloud storage or your own offsite storage.

**edit**

The free Crashplan program will backup your data to another offsite server of your choice.

Other options include any SFTP program.  Every backup program allows you to run a Post backup commands, so scripting it to upload to you chosen location gives a lot of flexibility.

Answer (score 4):

You could look at [Crashplan](http://www.crashplan.com) - it has Windows, Linux, and Mac clients, is available for free (you only pay to use their online backup storage), and has backup encryption.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [duplicity](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/) or [Duplicati](https://code.google.com/p/duplicati/). Both can encrypt your backup using GnuPG and transfer it securely to the offsite server, using SFTP/SCP/SSH or various protocols over SSL. Duplicity is older, easier to script and should be available for whatever Linux distro you use. Duplicati on the other hand is much easier to setup under Windows and can use the Volume Shadow Copy service under Windows to backup open files.

Biggest problem with both is the lack of software for the server. You'd have to install the software that uses the protocol you choose seperately.

Comment: Thanks. Is there software that supports both the client and server for Windows?

Comment: As mentioned in the other answers, Crashplan provides you with one software that acts as client and server. If you still want to use duplicity or duplicati, you'll need either [Apache HTTPd](http://httpd.apache.org), [Microsoft IIS](http://www.microsoft.com/iis) (WebDAV over SSL), [freeSSHd](http://www.freesshd.com), [OpenSSH](http://www.openssh.org) (SFTP) or a similar server.

Comment: Beware of Duplicati. I can confirm [this serious issue with GPG](https://github.com/duplicati/duplicati/issues/2270#issuecomment-431554427) on Duplicati - 2.0.4.23_beta_2019-07-14